# restoring with mysqldump, but where is the data?

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I'm in need to restore a table and I do:

```
mysqldump --opt database table_name < table_name.sql
```

I hit enter and Done! Well, not really, when I go to see if there is anything on the table it show 0 records.

I have look into the table_name.sql and I see two records.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`mysqldump` is the wrong command for restoring from a backup.

You need to run `mysql`, as in, the mysql client.  It's generally something like this:

`mysql -u username -p database_name < sqlfile.sql`

That will use your file as input to the mysql client, which subsequently executes the SQL.

Comment: Ok, getting one step further. Now I'm getting: Table 'table_name' already exists. Do can I import the data then?

Comment: You'll have to drop the table first before you can import a dumped table.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` just exports the data to an SQL script. You can restore with this:

```
mysql db < file.sql
```